# How to check validity of strings to a set of numerical masks?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field that I need to check validity of the input.

The input needs to be 4 digits with the following masks:

```
08## and 09##, 4###, 5###, 6###, 7###
```

String examples:

```
"1234" // invalid
"abcd" // invalid
"5000" // valid
"0810" // valid
```

What is a regex that I can use to check the strings validity?

Something like:

```
regex.test('1234')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex pattern:

```
^(?:0[89]\d{2}|[4-7]\d{3})$
```

Sample script:

```js
var input = ["1234", "abcd", "5000", "0810"];

input.forEach(x => console.log(x + " => " + /^(?:0[89]\d{2}|[4-7]\d{3})$/.test(x)));
```

The regex used here says to match:

- `^` from the start of the string

  - `(?:`

    - `0[89]\d{2}` starts with 08 or 09, followed by any 2 digits
    - `|` OR
    - `[4-7]\d{3}` starts with 4, 5, 6, 7, followed by any 3 digits
  - `)`
- `$` end of the string

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
const regex = /^(08\d{2}|09\d{2}|[4-7]\d{3})$/;
console.log(regex.test('1234')); 
console.log(regex.test('abcd'));
console.log(regex.test('ABCD'));
console.log(regex.test('ABcD'));
console.log(regex.test('5000'));
console.log(regex.test('0810'));
```

- ^ start of the string.
- 08\d{2}, 09\d{2}  matches "08" and "09" followed by any two digits
- [4-7]\d{3} matches a digit from 4 to 7 followed by any three digits.
- $ end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern.

```
0[89]\d\d|[4-7]\d{3}
```

Here is the *Wikipedia* article on regular expressions.
*[Wikipedia – Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

The syntax is very basic, despite appearing somewhat arcane.

You provide the static text you want to match, and when a character can range in value, you utilize the syntax—i.e., `\d`, or `[4-7]`.

It doesn't take long to learn, the *Wikipedia* article covers it, entirely.

There are also some great books, O'Reilly Media has a few good ones.
*[O'Reilly Media – Mastering Regular Expressions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/)*.